# Required device capabilities for iPad Wifi only

Tags: ios, ipad, compatibility, core-location

I recently published an app in the AppStore. Many users are getting the device compatibility message and it seems that all of them are having an iPad WiFi only.
My app need location of the user but it don't need an accurate one. 
Currently in the Info.plist I've location-services and gps under the required device capabilities.

My question is: If I remove these two requirements from the info.plist. Will my app be able to execute and get location whenever it's possible?

Sorry for asking but I have no real devices to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove the `gps` capability

Apple's documentation regarding the `gps` capability key:

> Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the presence of GPS (or AGPS) hardware when tracking locations. (**You should include this key only if you need the higher accuracy offered by GPS hardware.**) If you include this key, you should also include the location-services key. **You should require GPS only if your app needs location data more accurate than the cellular or Wi-fi radios might otherwise provide.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: So if I have understand quietly, I need to remove the gps capability as you mentioned. But does this solve my issue? Does iPad Wifi only users will be able to download it?

Comment: @MNIFAKRAM That should solve the issue. The capability is currently restricting those devices from downloading because they don't have a real gps built in